# MySQL MAX Value using GROUP BY skipping entries

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have some data in an sql table called entries

```
username    location    species date    length  weight  timestamp   id
    BooF    Black Lake  Smallmouth Bass 2014-08-12  12  1   2014-08-04 12:58:00 1
    BooF    Black Lake  Largemouth Bass 2014-08-13  15  2   2014-08-04 12:58:00 2
    BooF    Black Lake  Largemouth Bass 2014-08-19  20  5   2014-08-04 12:58:00 3
    BooF    Lake Bonaparte  Smallmouth Bass 2014-08-13  13  1   2014-08-04 12:58:00 4
    BooF    Lake Bonaparte  Largemouth Bass 2014-08-28  14  2   2014-08-04 12:58:00 5
    BooF    Black Lake  Largemouth Bass 2014-08-27  18  3   2014-08-04 13:22:03 6
    BooF    Lake Bonaparte  Smallmouth Bass 2014-08-19  14.3    3.4 2014-08-05 16:58:47 8
    BooF    Cranberry Lake  Walleye 2014-08-05  10  1   2014-08-18 17:14:00 10
    BooF    Cranberry Lake  Walleye 2014-08-05  10  1   2014-08-18 17:16:28 11
            Indian Lake Walleye 2014-08-05  10  1   2014-08-18 17:30:14 13
    BooF    Indian Lake Walleye 2014-08-05  10  1   2014-08-18 17:34:38 14
    BooF    Crystal Lake    Walleye 2014-08-06  10  4   2014-08-18 17:35:29 15
    BooF    Hudson River    Walleye 2014-08-11  10  2   2014-08-19 15:29:19 16
    BooF    Indian River    Northern Pike   2014-08-05  20  2   2014-08-26 09:46:03 17
            Hudson River    Smallmouth Bass 2014-08-05  12  1   2014-08-26 09:47:14 18
    BooF    Hyde Lake   Pickerel    2014-08-06  20  2   2014-08-26 09:48:24 20
--> BooF    Lake Ozonia Walleye 2014-08-14  20  3   2014-08-26 10:10:59 23
--> BooF    Mud Lake    Walleye 2014-08-14  21  2   2014-08-26 10:10:59 24
    Daswabbage  Lake Ontario    White Crappie   2014-08-12  15  20  2014-08-26 12:25:00 26
    Daswabbage  Lake Ontario    White Crappie   2014-08-06  16  21  2014-08-26 12:25:49 27
    Daswabbage  Butterfield Lake    Black Crappie   2014-08-13  5   2   2014-08-26 12:27:00 28
    Daswabbage  Black River Smallmouth Bass 2014-08-12  12  2   2014-08-26 12:28:09 29
    Daswabbage  Cranberry Lake  Smallmouth Bass 2014-08-20  5   5   2014-08-26 12:34:10 30
    Daswabbage  Clear Lake  Smallmouth Bass 2014-08-05  3   6   2014-08-26 12:41:52 31
    Daswabbage  Clear Lake  Smallmouth Bass 2014-08-06  10  7   2014-08-26 13:00:48 32
    BooF    Cranberry Lake  Pickerel    2014-08-07  15  5   2014-08-26 15:13:45 34
    BooF    Cranberry Lake  Pickerel    2014-08-02  13  6   2014-08-26 15:15:08 35
    BooF    Butterfield Lake    White Crappie   2014-08-18  10  26  2014-08-26 15:15:42 36
--> BooF    Lake Ozonia Walleye 2014-08-31  9   5   2014-08-26 15:17:18 37
--> BooF    Grass Lake  White Crappie   2014-08-11  15  30  2014-08-26 15:18:52 38
--> BooF    Grass Lake  White Crappie   2014-08-20  15  30  2014-08-26 16:06:44 39
--> BooF    Crystal Lake    White Crappie   2014-08-20  6   10  2014-08-26 16:59:32 43
```

I am trying to gather the MAX length for each species for a particular user.  I have tried

```
"SELECT length.* FROM entries length 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT species, MAX(length) AS  MaxLength 
    FROM entries WHERE username = 'BooF' GROUP BY species) 
    groupedlength ON   
    length.species = groupedlength.species AND length.length = groupedlength.MaxLength 
    ORDER BY species"
```

And I have also tried

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM entries ORDER BY length DESC) tmp 
    WHERE username='BooF' GROUP BY species
```

Which both ways seem to yield the same results of

```
username    location    species date    length  weight  timestamp   id
    BooF    Black Lake  Largemouth Bass 2014-08-19  20  5   2014-08-04 12:58:00 3
    BooF    Indian River    Northern Pike   2014-08-05  20  2   2014-08-26 09:46:03 17
    BooF    Hyde Lake   Pickerel    2014-08-06  20  2   2014-08-26 09:48:24 20
    BooF    Lake Bonaparte  Smallmouth Bass 2014-08-19  14.3    3.4 2014-08-05 16:58:47 8
    BooF    Lake Ozonia Walleye 2014-08-31  9   5   2014-08-26 15:17:18 37
    BooF    Crystal Lake    White Crappie   2014-08-20  6   10  2014-08-26 16:59:32 43
```

Which if you can read through my garbled mess that for walleye and white crappie they are wrong.  length of 9 and length of 6 are clearly not the MAX lengths for those fish in my original data.  I believe I am doing my functions correctly but am unclear why they are skipping over numbers that are higher then the data being output.  Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` is invalid and would have been rejected by every other DBMS: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you show. I tested your query against your sample data on MySQL 5.6.19 and it returns correct results. Are you sure you're querying the right table, and that it does have the values you expect? Try `select species, min(length), max(length) from entries where username ='BooF' group by species;`

Comment: Yes I am positive I am running it on the correct table.  Its the only table I have with those stats in it.  I am not sure how you are getting different results...

Comment: @BillKarwin I ran your query and this was the result

`species     min(length) max(length)
Largemouth Bass 14 20
Northern Pike 20 20
Pickerel 13 20
Smallmouth Bass 12 14.3
Walleye         10 9
White Crappie 10 6`

And they are still incorrect for the MAX sizes

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your strange results only by using a string data type for `length`, because the string "10" is *lexically* less than the string "9" or "6". Therefore the greatest string value is not necessarily the greatest value numerically when the two numbers have a different number of digits.

```
mysql> SELECT 10 < 9;
+--------+
| 10 < 9 |
+--------+
|      0 |
+--------+

mysql> SELECT '10' < '9';
+------------+
| '10' < '9' |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
```

You should store your `length` as a `DECIMAL(9,1)` data type, not a string.

Another solution is to coerce the length values to numerics as you compute the MAX():

```
SELECT length.* FROM entries length 
INNER JOIN (SELECT species, MAX(CAST(length AS DECIMAL(9,1))) AS  MaxLength 
    FROM entries WHERE username = 'BooF' GROUP BY species) AS groupedlength 
ON length.species = groupedlength.species AND length.length = groupedlength.MaxLength 
WHERE length.username = 'BooF'
ORDER BY species
```

In my test, that correctly finds the entries matching the maximum values:

```
+----+----------+----------------+-----------------+------------+--------+--------+---------------------+
| id | username | location       | species         | date       | length | weight | timestamp           |
+----+----------+----------------+-----------------+------------+--------+--------+---------------------+
|  3 | BooF     | Black Lake     | Largemouth Bass | 2014-08-19 | 20     | 5      | 2014-08-04 12:58:00 |
| 17 | BooF     | Indian River   | Northern Pike   | 2014-08-05 | 20     | 2      | 2014-08-26 09:46:03 |
| 20 | BooF     | Hyde Lake      | Pickerel        | 2014-08-06 | 20     | 2      | 2014-08-26 09:48:24 |
|  8 | BooF     | Lake Bonaparte | Smallmouth Bass | 2014-08-19 | 14.3   | 3.4    | 2014-08-05 16:58:47 |
| 24 | BooF     | Mud Lake       | Walleye         | 2014-08-14 | 21     | 2      | 2014-08-26 10:10:59 |
| 38 | BooF     | Grass Lake     | White Crappie   | 2014-08-11 | 15     | 30     | 2014-08-26 15:18:52 |
| 39 | BooF     | Grass Lake     | White Crappie   | 2014-08-20 | 15     | 30     | 2014-08-26 16:06:44 |
+----+----------+----------------+-----------------+------------+--------+--------+---------------------+
```

However, you may notice that it finds *any* entry matching the maximum values. So there are two rows for White Crappie, because both are tied, and both match the max value. I don't know if you intended this.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the `Max length` it's a simple aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(length), species FROM entries WHERE username = 'BooF' group by species
```

if you need the other columns of the table related with the max-record, too it becomes more tricky. 
Note that simply adding the required columns (or select `*` without aggregations)  will NOT give the correct result, as you are missing an aggregation on those columns. (MsSQL will clearly throw an Error, mysql is returning something undefined for columns on which you don't apply an aggregation)

Assuming you want to have the other columns associated to the record in question also, you can do the following:

- Join the table with itself
- Add a comparision `<` to the join condition to make sure you are getting the largest entry per table.
- Then select every result where the RIGHT resultset `isnull` - cause that one has NO match that is LARGER -> It's the largest result row.

Like:

```
SELECT
  `left`.*
FROM
  entries `left`
LEFT JOIN
  entries `right`
ON
  `left`.species = `right`.species -- only compare the same species
  AND `left`.username = `right`.username -- only compare  for the same user
  AND `left`.length < `right`.length -- smaller result on the left side.
WHERE
  ISNULL(`right`.id); -- choose the one that has no larger match.
  AND `left`.username = 'BooF' -- just for BooF.
```

ps.: `left` and `right` are dumb table aliases, as they are reserved keywords  :)

Comment: There must be something wrong in my sql table then because this query returns the same results I get with the other 2 queries.  If I delete the line with ID 43 it gives me the correct result for white crappie but as soon as I enter another value in, it shows the new value as the longest even though its not.  Any idea what would be causing this?